# URL rewrite with subdomain and additional parameters

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a variant subdomain that requires rewrite and multiple additional parameters at the back of the url after the slashes.

My current rewrite rules are as follows:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((?!www).+)\.classifiedads4free\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(?:jpe?g|png|gif|bmp|php)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) pages/list.php?country=%1&category=%2 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule    ^cat/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)?$      pages/list.php?category=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

I can access each individual rewrite as in 
when i go to `http://us.classifiedads4free.com`. I can read the country parameter.
when i go to `http://classifiedads4free.com/cat/jobs`, i can read the category parameter.

But I'm not able to get the correct parameters for `http://us.classifiedads4free.com/cat/jobs`.

Only the country parameters gets shown. How do I make it such that both parameters are accounted for?

Answer (score 0):

You can only have one rule per `RewriteCond(s)` so you need to include the condition that picks the country again along with the rule. And you will still need the standalone rule for when the country code is absent.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((?!www).+)\.classifiedads4free\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(?:jpe?g|png|gif|bmp|php)$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^cat/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)?$ pages/list.php?country=%1&category=$1 [QSA,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((?!www).+)\.classifiedads4free\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(?:jpe?g|png|gif|bmp|php)$ [NC]
  RewriteRule (.*) pages/list.php?country=%1&category=%2 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule    ^cat/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)?$      pages/list.php?category=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

Also it's important the rule is first, otherwise `(.*)` will consume `cat/...` and select the wrong rule